# gitlab-ci - re-evaluation of variables breaks the "if" rule

Tags: if-statement, gitlab-ci, rules

I have the following gitlab-ci yaml:

```yaml
job:
  stage: cool-stage
  variables:
    PUSH: "push"
    FOO: $PUSH
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == $PUSH'
      when: always
  script:
    - echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
    - echo $PUSH
    - echo $FOO
    - echo $( [[ $FOO == $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE ]] && echo "FOO equals" || echo "not equals" )
    - echo $( [[ $PUSH == $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE ]] && echo "PUSH equals" || echo "not equals" )
    - bash print-ascii-values.sh
```

It works fine, launches the `script` on each push and outputs the following:

```
$ echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
push
$ echo $PUSH
push
$ echo $FOO
push
$ echo $( [[ $FOO == $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE ]] && echo "FOO equals" || echo "not equals" )
FOO equals
$ echo $( [[ $PUSH == $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE ]] && echo "PUSH equals" || echo "not equals" )
PUSH equals
$ bash print-ascii-values.sh
 
PUSH
112 117 115 104  
FOO
112 117 115 104  
CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
112 117 115 104 
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

BUT! If I change the `if` rule to use `FOO` instead of `PUSH`, the pipeline doesn't run.

Why is that? What do I miss?

Comment: Seems like a known issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/327780

Comment: so I'm not crazy. Thank you @ChrisDoyle :)

Comment: This epic discusses it more https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/8662